# react native clear webview history

Tags: webview, react-native

In my app I would like to clear webview history after a button click. Is there any method like clearhistory on webview in react native?

Something like:

```
onClearHistoryButtonClick = (event) => {
  this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].clearhistory();
};
```

Comment: No. This functionality is not available in react-native right now. You may achieve this by modifying 'ReactWebView' class inside react-native source code for Android and send a PR to react native team :)

Answer (score 0):

It's `webview cookies` that need to be cleared.
It has already been answered in [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597732/how-to-clear-react-native-webview-cookies/44603171#44603171)

Comment: Clearing cookies isn't the same as clearing history. Even after clearing cookies (via `CookieManager.clearAll();`), the user will still be able to hit the 'Back' button to go back to the last visited page.

Comment: The answered question does not work on RN 0.60 and above