# How to clear react native webview cookies?

Tags: javascript, webview, react-native

How to clear react native webview cookies?

When I re-open the page, it remembers my account if I logged in on a website. But I don't want that.

Can I do this by injecting javascript?

Comment: yes you can clear cookies through JavaScript

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solved by using this: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cookies

```
CookieManager.clearAll();
```

Comment: This package and its alternatives do not work on RN 0.60

Comment: This library does not provide support for RN >= 0.60

Comment: Use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cookies instead. This version works well with RN >= 0.60. I am currently using this package with react-native 0.61.5 without any issues.

Answer (score 15):

I used incognito mode as a turnaround and it worked perfect for me.

```js
<WebView
  incognito={true}
  userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
  source={{
    uri:
      'your url',
  }}
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
/>
```

Comment: Great answer. Works for iOS and Android and does not need any extra dependencies!

Answer (score 12):

At the time I'm posting, `CookieManager` has [poor support](https://github.com/react-native-community/cookies#platforms-supported) for Expo, I had problems clearing cookies after changing a password.

In 2020, **for those using Expo**, this works:

```
const RCTNetworking = require('react-native/Libraries/Network/RCTNetworking')
RCTNetworking.clearCookies(() => { })
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution without using any third party libraries.

```
var RCTNetworking = require(“RCTNetworking”);
RCTNetworking.clearCookies(() => {});
```

Comment: You need to have explained this

Comment: I am using old Instagram API which requires the cookies to be deleted in order for the user to logout. This solution does not clear the cookies.

Comment: yes, this doesn't appear to clear cookies from [react-native-linkedin](https://github.com/xcarpentier/react-native-linkedin/) either