# Set react-native webview cookies for domain

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have read this [How to clear react native webview cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597732/how-to-clear-react-native-webview-cookies) ok, but if I want to clean cookies only for one domain, or moreover exactly cookie for exactly domain?

I try to do this -

```
let c = MYCOOKIE + '=; path=/; secure; HttpOnly'
let cookie;

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    cookie = {
        'Set-Cookie': c
    }
} else {
    cookie = c;
}

CookieManager.setFromResponse(MYDOMAIN, cookie).then(r => 
    this.setState({showVebwiew: true}));
```

And render webview. But this settings have effect for `CookieManager.get` but not set cookie in webview...

Answer (score 0):

I use [react-native-cookie](https://github.com/shimohq/react-native-cookie) to clear cookies for www.instagram.com only. The package takes a string (website name) as an argument.

The package is not maintained anymore but it's very simple and has been working fine for me for 2 years. I started using it from `RN 0.54` and now it's working on `RN 0.59.10`. I use it to clear cookies for instagram.com so new users can log in through the Instagram REST API. It opens the Instagram login page in a web view.

**NOTE**
This package or any of its alternatives like [this](https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies) one do not support auto-linking and therefore do not work on `RN 0.60` or above.