# Clear browser cookies React Native 0.60

Tags: react-native, cookies, react-native-instagram-login

My app is using Instagram's REST API, in order for a user to logout and login with a different account I have to clear the cookies for www.instagram.com from the browser. I have been using [react-native-cookie](https://github.com/shimohq/react-native-cookie) with `RN 0.59.10` and it has been working fine.

After upgrading to `RN 0.60` I can't use the `react-native-cookie` or any of its alternate packages because they don't support auto-linking. The solution I have found is using the `RCTNetworking` module from the react-native library. You can see the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56448966/7027615).

### Code

```
var RCTNetworking = require('RCTNetworking');

export const logout = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    RCTNetworking.clearCookies(result => {
      if (!result) {
        console.log('Error Message');
        reject()
      }

      store.dispatch({ type: "RESET_APP_STATE" });
      NavigationService.navigate("AuthLoading");
      resolve()
    });
  });
};
```

The code runs fine. The app's state is cleared and the user is navigated to the login screen, but when I open the Instagram page in the `webView` instead of asking for the username and password, it directly logs me in.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the community-version of react-native-cookies which can be found here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-cookies

I am happily using this in combination with version 0.61.5 of React-Native.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.